# Java ID3 audio tags lib

Tags: java, clojure, tags, mp3, ogg

I'm looking for a good libraries to edit .mp3 tags ID3v(22,23,24) (like author, title, track and this kind of stuff), write in java or clojure, any ideas ?

There is some standard "de facto" in this field...

I have just look at this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73147/i-need-an-id3-tag-reader-library-for-java-preferably-a-fast-one
But if there is something more would be great...

Perfect would be if the libraries supported not only .mp3 but also .ogg and .wma...

Thanks everybody, and sorry for my English...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JAudiotagger` library [JAudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/)

Comment: but it still work on java 1.4 and don't run on MacOS... is not a big deal for me, but i find somethings more portable...

Comment: in that case you can give `JID3` a look [JID3](http://jid3.blinkenlights.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I built a Swing project last year that used [JAudioTagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/), and it worked great.
I only added support for mp3 to my app, but I believe it support more than that.

Comment: I can give you the link to the git repos if you want to see how I used it.

Comment: [mp3regex](https://github.com/kcdragon/mp3regex)

Comment: The project is a find/replace regular expression tool for mp3 tags.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late, but maybe it will help someone. I also wanted a library for this, so I wrote a library supporting all of the commonly used tag fields in mp3, ogg, flac, and mp4/m4a files. Source and documentation can be found here: https://github.com/DanPallas/green-tags and it is up on clojars.